# Load data into partition bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to load avro files stored in GCS into big query partition table.
below command works fine and loads data into current day partition

```
bq --location=US load --source_format=AVRO pari.datatable "gs://pari-gcp-dataflow/2018/07/21/12/*"
```

but when I try to load data into specific partition, it does not work.

```
bq --location=US load --source_format=AVRO pari.datatable$20180721 "gs://pari-gcp-dataflow/2018/07/21/12/*"
```

Comment: Not sure what shell you ran the command in, but in bash I need to quote the table name as otherwise bash would try to replace "$20180721", e.g, "bq ... 'pari.datatable$20180721'".

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly happens with me. I enclose the  single quotes and it worked